# ruby on rails iterating params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a client that is sending params such as age, gender, name and so on.
I need to retrieve data from the table based on the params, but first I need to check for the presence of the param(to avoid a null param and therefore an empty result). The params are working as filters, so they can be triggered or they can be left blanck.
What I am doing right now is

```
@retieve = Student.all
  unless params[:age].nil?
    @retrieve = @retrieve.where(age: params[:age])
end
   unless params[:gender].nil?
    @retrieve = @retrieve.where(gender: params[:gender])
end
```

and so on for every param I receive. This way I check if the filter has been selected, and if it has I use the selection as a parameter for the query
It works, but as Ruby is known for the DRY statement, I am pretty sure someone out there knows a better way for putting this and to make this flexible.
Thank you for whatever answer or suggestion you will provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work best if all of these filters were in a subhash of `params` that you can iterate over without including unwanted parameters (eg the `:action` and `:controller` parameters that rails adds)

Once you've done that you could do

```
(params[:filters] || {}).inject(Student.all) do |scope, (key, value)|
  scope.where(key => value)
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Student.where(params[:filters])` be enough?

Comment: @ Frederick Cheung - I am tryng to understand how your code works, but I can't get it right :(
Could you please explain it? It really looks like it is what I am looking for!
Thank you

Comment: @jack - as commented it doesn't achieve much over `Student.where(params[:filters])`

Comment: Assuming that they're actually missing from params when not set

Comment: Assuming that they're actually missing from params when not set

Comment: Hard to search for age with this approach, unless your looking for the exact age.  If you have a birthdate or a need a range, you'll want to use a predefined scope that can do a little logic.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this sort of thing and you have options for how far you want to go at this stage.

Two big things I'd consider -

1) Make nice scopes that allow you to send a param and ignore it if it's nil.  That way you can just append another scope for each param from the form and it will be ignored without using `if` or `unless`

2) Move the search into a separate class (a concern) to keep your controller clean.

Here's a blog post that talks about some of the concepts (too much to post in this answer).  There is lots of info on the web about this, I searched on the web under "rails search filter params concern" to get an example for you.

http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/02/17/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/

Comment: Thanks! The blog you linked is really good, thanks for sharing it!